# Dynamic forescat in ARIMA model

Tags: arima, forecast

Good Night, when I do a forecast in ARIMA model, por example AR(1), the result is a straight line. I see that when we use a "Dynamic Forecast", the result is not a straight line. ¿Who can i do a dynamic forecast or package in R that do this?

Answer (score 0):

check this out [Arrima R](https://predictivehacks.com/arima-r/). It may be helpful to you.